# Eject / unmount ghost external disk on macOS

Tags: external-disk, mount, eject

I use MacBook Air Mid 2013 (1.3 GHz Intel Core i5, 4 GB 1600 MHz DDR3, Intel HD Graphics 5000 1536 MB, 128GB flash storage) running macOS Sierra 10.12

```
$ sw_vers
ProductName:   Mac OS X
ProductVersion:   10.12
BuildVersion:  16A323
```

I have an external hard disk (Western Digital WD Elements for 1TB USB3) which I use for external storage for big files. It partitioned into 2 partitions: `JUMBO` (HFS+, 794.8 GB, encrypted) and `JUMBO 2` (exFAT, 205.0 GB).

The problem is that sometimes (especially when I use it for one or more days without ejecting) when I eject disk and then connect again it doesn't "mount". I can see/use only exFAT partition. I tried to unmount and eject everything using `diskutil` but it doesn't help.

```
$ diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *121.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage Macintosh HD            120.5 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3

/dev/disk1 (internal, virtual):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            Macintosh HD           +120.1 GB   disk1
                                 Logical Volume on disk0s2
                                 EEFEF749-BA27-42D1-9B89-DA793E10F33D
                                 Unencrypted

/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk2
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk2s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage JUMBO                   794.8 GB   disk2s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Boot OS X               134.2 MB   disk2s3
   4:       Microsoft Basic Data                         205.0 GB   disk2s4

/dev/disk3 (external, virtual):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                                                   +794.5 GB   disk3
                                 Logical Volume JUMBO on disk2s2
                                 3E1DB12A-A176-4A2A-BE65-5CC7D25C8582
                                 Locked Encrypted

/dev/disk4 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk4
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk4s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage                         794.8 GB   disk4s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Boot OS X               134.2 MB   disk4s3
   4:       Microsoft Basic Data JUMBO 2                 205.0 GB   disk4s4

Offline
                                 Logical Volume JUMBO on disk2s2
                                 3E1DB12A-A176-4A2A-BE65-5CC7D25C8582
                                 Locked Encrypted
```

So, I tried to unmount all disks (2, 3, 4) and then eject them:

```
$ diskutil unmountDisk force /dev/disk2
Forced unmount of all volumes on disk2 was successful
$ diskutil unmountDisk force /dev/disk3
Forced unmount of all volumes on disk3 was successful
$ diskutil unmountDisk force /dev/disk4
Forced unmount of all volumes on disk4 was successful
$ diskutil eject /dev/disk2
Disk /dev/disk2 ejected
$ diskutil eject /dev/disk3
Volume failed to eject
$ diskutil eject /dev/disk4
Disk /dev/disk4 ejected
```

After this, I disconnect the disk and receive this:

```
$ diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *121.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage Macintosh HD            120.5 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3

/dev/disk1 (internal, virtual):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            Macintosh HD           +120.1 GB   disk1
                                 Logical Volume on disk0s2
                                 EEFEF749-BA27-42D1-9B89-DA793E10F33D
                                 Unencrypted

/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk2
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk2s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage JUMBO                   794.8 GB   disk2s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Boot OS X               134.2 MB   disk2s3
   4:       Microsoft Basic Data                         205.0 GB   disk2s4

/dev/disk3 (external, virtual):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                                                   +794.5 GB   disk3
                                 Logical Volume JUMBO on disk2s2
                                 3E1DB12A-A176-4A2A-BE65-5CC7D25C8582
                                 Locked Encrypted

/dev/disk4 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk4
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk4s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage                         794.8 GB   disk4s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Boot OS X               134.2 MB   disk4s3
   4:       Microsoft Basic Data JUMBO 2                 205.0 GB   disk4s4

Offline
                                 Logical Volume JUMBO on disk2s2
                                 3E1DB12A-A176-4A2A-BE65-5CC7D25C8582
                                 Locked Encrypted
```

So, I can't get rid of it.

The problem resolves using reboot, but I need to do that without reboot. Do anyone have any ideas?

**PS:** Also, forgot to mentioned that no programs are using files from the disk:

```
$ lsof | grep "JUMBO"
```

gives no results.

**UPD:** So, after reboot, *ghost* drive disappeared:

```
$ diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *121.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage Macintosh HD            120.5 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3

/dev/disk1 (internal, virtual):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            Macintosh HD           +120.1 GB   disk1
                                 Logical Volume on disk0s2
                                 EEFEF749-BA27-42D1-9B89-DA793E10F33D
                                 Unencrypted
```

And after I connect it, it was automatically detected and mounted, and everything works as usual:

```
$ diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *121.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage Macintosh HD            120.5 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3

/dev/disk1 (internal, virtual):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            Macintosh HD           +120.1 GB   disk1
                                 Logical Volume on disk0s2
                                 EEFEF749-BA27-42D1-9B89-DA793E10F33D
                                 Unencrypted

/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk2
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk2s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage JUMBO                   794.8 GB   disk2s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Boot OS X               134.2 MB   disk2s3
   4:       Microsoft Basic Data JUMBO 2                 205.0 GB   disk2s4

/dev/disk3 (external, virtual):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            JUMBO                  +794.5 GB   disk3
                                 Logical Volume on disk2s2
                                 3E1DB12A-A176-4A2A-BE65-5CC7D25C8582
                                 Unlocked Encrypted
```